# Defining an array of structs

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I have data that I would like to assign to an array of structs.

Kind of like how you can do this:

```
int foo [5] = { 16, 2, 77, 40, 12071 };
```

Why doesn't this work for something like this:

Defining the structure type.

```
struct Creature {
  std::string name;
  int x, y;
};
```

Then for the array.

```
const Creature list[NUM_CREATURES] = {
  name = "Walrus";
  x = 2; y = 6;,
  name = "Sardine";
  x = 3; y = 1;,
  name = "Seahorse";
  x = 4; y = 2;,
  name = "Jellyfish";
  x = 1; y = 10;,
  name = Dolphin";
  x = 8; y = 4;
  }
```

I have all of this located in the header file. I am defining this list as a constant as I will use these to fill another larger array then sorting the array by the size of the x and y dimensions.

Comment: Note that solutions that can be used in [tag:c] are probably not valid in [tag:c++] so I removed the [tag:c] tag.

Comment: @Slava I knew the syntax was wrong, that's why I asked the question. Thank you for your input.

Comment: @NicholasDapprich you should formulate your question properly. For example: "how can I initialize such structure, I tried this way and it does not work" would have very different response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to initialize each struct in the initializer.

```
const Creature list[NUM_CREATURES] = {
  { "Walrus", 2, 6 },
  { "Sardine", 3, 1 },
  ...
}
```

With uniform initialization you don't need to do *(and cant do)* `name=`/`x=`/ect

Comment: Thanks a lot, makes sense. The different types threw me off.

Comment: It's not that you "don't need" it's that you "can't use" in C++.

Comment: C++20 may add a basic version of designated initializers